# When answering "How did you hear about us?" while applying online, what does "external" mean?

Tags: applications

I'm currently applying for a position online and I'm having trouble filling out one of the fields. There's a field that asks "How did you hear about us?" and gives a drop-down list of options. I was directed to this position I'm applying for because I know the vice president of the company and she graciously gave my resume to the recruiting department who then told me to apply for this position. In the drop-down list, 90% of the choices are the names of different job search websites, and then at the bottom of the list are the choices "Internal Candidate" and "COMPANY_NAME External" (COMPANY_NAME was replaced with the name of the company).

I read online that Internal Candidate refers to somebody who is currently an employee at the company but for a different position. I couldn't find anything about what the other choice meant. Could somebody else fill me in?

Unfortunately this listing doesn't even include an "Other" choice, so if the "External" option doesn't pertain to me, I really don't know what I should put.

Comment: Voting to close: ask the company.

Comment: So the VP of the company referred you and one option is the company?

Comment: I read it as "none of above" or "Other...", which you are missing.

Answer (score 4):

I should not worry about it too much. It is not used in your recruitment. It is used by the HR department to figure out where to spend their money on looking for candidates.

Just select a random one.

Comment: Sometimes, but beware that some companies are known to give preference to candidates recommended by employees, or conversely they penalize candidates who came in externally (cold-emailed jobs@, website, jobs boards etc. etc.)